# Redesigning MOSFET switches

Tags: power, mosfet

Consider the two circuits below, the first is the original:

[image]

When HIBERNATE goes high, it switches the MOSFETs Q1 and Q2. However, because of the 10 kΩ bias resistors built into BJT Q3, it pulls considerable amount of current from HIBERNATE. Since this device is operated with a coin battery, it is a problem.

I have replaced Q3, with an N-channel MOSFET, like in the image below:

[image]

I have measured it all, and both circuits work. But I need some comments on it. Perhaps a different MOSFET? Also I am not sure what will happen if the circuit is fed with reverse current. The first design is protected against reverse voltage, but maybe it will not work as designed with the BJT replaced with a MOSFET. I need comments please.

Comment: Where is the `HIBERNATE` signal coming from? What is the brand/model of the MOSFET Q6?

Comment: Why does this design look like it never hibernates with Pch sources tied  below V+ to nothing except a 100k Pull down R? When you might think a simple High side power switch (1 Pch) is all you need from. 30V ?? Power source. (?-1)

Comment: @RohatKılıç `HIBERNATE` is coming from a microcontroller, tm4c123, and that part of microcontroller is powered by a coin battery. the Q6 is a BSS138

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with an MOS transistors. No problem.

The BJT had an internal resistive divider to increase the threshold where the switch "flips". I am wondering why was it implemented inside the BJT. The transistor is less versatile this way. But I also not see any reason why a BJT should be used here. The current it has to supply is very low, in the 10uA range. An MOS transistor in general is a better switch. The only critical point might be the higher sensitivity of an MOS gate to an ESD event. If the control signal comes from a switch (i.e. not from an electronic circuit) you might consider adding some ESD protection. The base terminal of a BJT is basically a diode, which protects itself for every cases, but the most extreme ones.

Comment: Thank you @horror-vacui. I have constructed both circuits, using bss138lt1g as mos. And it works nice, with no problems. I was concerned with the zener diode inside the mosfet, but I understand all mosfets have those zeners to limit upper voltage by diode break down.

Comment: @CamBazz not all MOS transistors have the zener. Though there is always* a bulk-drain pn junction. It is a reverse biased diode, but if it breaks down due to excess voltage, the magic smoke is released. Since you have 100kOhm at the drain, the bulk-drain diode have to protect itself. There is no possibility that significant energy will flow through those 100kOhms, unless you have some significant AC signal at the output, which are capacitively coupled to the drain. *MOS on SOI technology has no bulk-drain pn-junction.

Comment: in this case, is it better to use a mos transistor with zener or without? Also, what are the practices for ESD protection in a circuit like this. I have found out it is a little `trigger happy` if I touch the gate of the mosfet with a tweezers it will start conducting.

Comment: @CamBazz triggering: it is a high impedance node, so if anything is coupled there, it will not be attenuated, and it will not discharge by itself. Determine the default state and pull the gate towards the appropriate with a big resistor. (it is not shown how the signal is generated).

Comment: @CamBazz I have no big experience in board level ESD, but diodes could be used there to derail the ESD energy into an ESD clamp. Putting a cap into the gate could help a bit, but in itself it is not an ESD protection.

Answer (score 1):

Both cases are protected against reverse voltage. That's what Q1 is there for. That will not change just by swapping Q3.

The n-mosfet is definitely more suited for your purpose, since the bipolar transistor requires some current to be polarized, if you want to have low quiescent currents, then the mosfet is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @Antenna-Guy. I was concerned that, if negative voltage occurs at the point where R11 connects to the D of the mosfet, because of the zener diode, it would cause a flow of current. But that is not the case. I want to pull as little current as possible from the hibernate pin connected to the G of mosfet.